# function within a class' scope but not executed on the class python

Tags: python, function, class, nameerror

I'm writing a class to get data from an API. I have functions that I want to perform on the class e.g.

```
self.do_this()
```

I also have functions that are supposed to do things within that function, e.g.

```
def do_this_part(response):
    Dict = {}
    for key, value in response.items():
        Dict[key] = value
    return Dict
```

I want to have a smaller function inside the class so that it always comes within the class. It will never be performed on the class but will be performed within multiple functions that will be performed in the class.

I am getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'do_this_part' is not defined
```

So clearly I'm not defining the function in the right place. My apologies if this is a fairly basic question that has been answered before, I searched and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: if `do_this_part` is inside the class, you need to call it as `self.do_this_part(response)`. Also you need to change its signature so that it takes `self` as the first argument, and `response` as the second.

Comment: Yes, adding to Robin's answer, please edit your function like this - def do_this_part(self, response):

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond and user 78910!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want to use a staticmethod.

```py
class C:
    def do_this(self):
        response = {}
        self.do_this_part(response)

    @staticmethod
    def do_this_part(response):
        Dict = {}:
        for key, value in response.items():
            Dict[key] = value
        return Dict
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to do something like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def do_this_part(self, response):
        # Implement your logic here
        print(f"Response parameter is {response}")


my_class = MyClass()
response = "yo"
my_class.do_this_part(response)
```